# Determining significance based on confidence interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Given is the task to determine which odds-ratios are statistically significant for the following data:

Family affluence

Boys (n = 625)

- High: Reference
- Medium, Odds-ratio: 0.53, 95% Confidence-Interval: 0.39,0.74
- Low, Odds-ratio: 0.89, 95% Confidence-Interval: 0.55,1.44

Girls (n = 690)

- High: Reference
- Medium, Odds-ratio: 0.77, 95% Confidence-Interval: 0.46, 1.27
- Low, Odds-ratio: 0.91, 95% Confidence-Interval: 0.52, 1.60

Apparently, significant is only "Medium, Odds-ratio: 0.53, 95% Confidence-Interval: 0.39,0.74" - why is that however? All Odds-ratio values seem to lie
within the confidence-interval? Hints very appreciated

Comment: You may get more answers if you convert 'odds-ratios' into probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the meaning of the CI of the OR.  The point estimate **always** lies inside the CI.  What determines whether the CI points to a significant result is if the CI contains the value $1$.  If it does not, then the OR is statistically significant at level $\alpha$.  The only CI for which this is true is the one you pointed out.  All the others contain $1$, thus they do not meet the criterion for statistical significance.  It is that simple.

Comment: got it! thank you!